# How to extract an id from facebook video link with regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to get value of URL parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940508/regex-to-get-value-of-url-parameter)

If you have a facebook link such as

> http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=107084586333124

What regular expression would extract the number at the end 107084586333124

edit: I use php

Comment: In which language? Why do you want a regular expression?

Comment: Or you can just split it? strUrl.split("?v=")[1] ...?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940508/regex-to-get-value-of-url-parameter) - it asks the exact same question. If you're doing this as a one off on the page itself, why not use something like `$_GET['v']`?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's built-in functions to reliably pull query string variables out of a URL. You would use something like:

```
parse_str(parse_url($url , PHP_URL_QUERY), $v);//where $v is not set yet or an empty array
$v = @$v['v'];//will now contain the value of v or be null if not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the PHP regex engine, but this simple regular expression should do the trick. You will find your number in the first capture group.

```
v=(\d+)
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace the following regexes with `""`.

```
.*?\?v\=
\D*.*
```

The remaining data is your number.

Comment: If you insist on using a regex for this, you're better off using `preg_match()`, so you find what you want without altering any existing data. Also, it's only one op.

Comment: @Walf I posted this answer [before any language was tagged](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8949424/1), and I don't know any PHP. :)